# Работа с иконками в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, плагин, graphics

Как из одной иконки сделать 5 для всех DPI экрана? Например, я нарисовал какой-то элемент для проекта в максимальном разрешении для xxxhdpi. Есть ли в Android Studio какие-то стандартные инструменты, чтобы сделать из этого элемента остальные разрешения под все экраны? Или может плагин какой, если нет стандартных способов.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Необходимо проделать следующие шаги в Android Studio:

1. Найти папку `res` и кликнуть по ней правой кнопкой мыши
2. Выбрать `New` -> `Image Assett`
3. Указать путь до иконки в `Image Path` и настроить дополнительные параметры по желанию
4. Нажать `Next` и `Finish`

После чего у вас в проекте появятся папки `mipmap-xxx` для каждого разрешения, в которых будут лежать ваши иконки.

Answer (score 7):

Да, есть хороший [плагин](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658?pr=idea):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Можно еще на [сайте](http://andrewreitz.com/Android-Drawable-Resizer/#) сгенерить. Или вот [здесь](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)

Comment: Alexey Shtanko,от души! мега крутой генератор!